# Leiningen is missing its dependencies. (On Windows)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to install Leiningen on Windows 7. Here is my steps:

Step 1. Download:

```
cd C:\application_bin\

git clone git@github.com:technomancy/leiningen.git
```

Step 2. Add `C:\application_bin\leiningen\bin` to system path.

Step 3. Run:

```
PS C:\Users\Nick> lein repl                                                  

Leiningen is missing its dependencies.                                  
Please run "lein bootstrap" in the leiningen-core/ directory            
with a stable release of Leiningen. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
```

I don't know what is missing, so I follow the instruction from this error message:

```
cd C:\application_bin\leiningen\leiningen-core

lein bootstrap

Leiningen is missing its dependencies.                                  
Please run "lein bootstrap" in the leiningen-core/ directory            
with a stable release of Leiningen. See CONTRIBUTING.md for details.
```

The error comes back again. What's wrong with my installation steps? What dependencies are missing?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution here:

http://onoffswitch.net/installing-leinigen-windows/

The problem is caused by a maual `wget` installation on Windows. The `lein.bat` checks wheter `wget, curl` exist, and whether in powershell (in which case it creates a .net webclient and downloads the target file).

Solution:

1. Remove `wget`. or
2. Change the order of the `powershell`, `wget` section in `lein.bat`. (details in the aforementioned link.)